# Chrome Bookmarks without sign in

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way in Windows 7 to retain bookmarks between Chrome sessions without signing in each time. I hate not being in charge of this behavior and being forced to sign in.
I have switched from Chrome to 99% Opera browsing.

Answer (score 1):

You bookmarks are saved without having to sign into Chrome. Check the bookmarks bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or the bookmarks organizer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Either you haven't saved them properly, or you're not looking at the bookmarks bar. if you want the bookmarks across multiple Chrome installations then you need sync